# WCF REST API, processing sent content

Tags: c#, .net, json, wcf, rest

I'm working on a small REST API I wish to run at home (nothing big, just maintaining some small parts of my server), and given it would be using tons of parameters, mostly objects, for each command, I'd rather send it as a JSON data package.

Questions are:
- Is it possible to attach a JSON string to a GET or DELETE HTTP call, from client side?
- How can one process the attached data on the server side?

Comment: 'tons of parameters', perhaps use a POST, pass object in the BODY, check out these samples: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/older-versions/build-restful-apis-with-aspnet-web-api

Comment: Yes, but I think sticking with the proper HTTP verbs would be better. In this case, I'm asking for information (GetMessages is the function), but I have to supply the system some extra information, objects, etc - which need to be there, and adding them to the URL would mean a kilometers-long URI.

Comment: You could pass the additional data as custom HTTP header(s) on the request and still use GET as fm the verb. However, I don't see a problem with using POST for these situations, as lcryder suggests, and I think it makes more sense then passing the data your service uses as metadata.

Comment: Is the request body considered metadata in this scenario? Because I think that would be the easiest solution to go with.